# Parse a changelog and extract changes for a version

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

I have a changelog file in markdown which contains all changes between each version of my app like that :

```
## Version 1.0.6

* first change
* second change
* third change

## Version 1.0.5

* first foo change
* second foo change

## Version 1.0.4

* and so on...
```

What I want is to extract in a **script** the changes content for a version. For example I would to extract the changes for the *version 1.0.5*, so it should print :

```
* first foo change
* second foo change
```

The ideal way would be `./getVersionChanges version filename` which would those 2 params :

`version` : the version to extract changes

`filename` : the filename to parse

How can I achieve this with sed, awk, grep, or whatever ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/1403/variables#t=201611061418048683413 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227583/passing-variable-to-awk-and-using-that-in-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A slightly more elaborate `awk` solution, which

- exits once the block of interest has been printed,
- ignores blank lines,
- doesn't include the header line.

```
awk -v ver=1.0.5 '
 /^## Version / { if (p) { exit }; if ($3 == ver) { p=1; next } } p && NF
' file
```

---

As script `getVersionChanges`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v ver="$1" '
 /^## Version / { if (p) { exit }; if ($3 == ver) { p=1; next } } p && NF
' "$2"
```

---

**Explanation:**

- Regex condition `/^## Version /` matches the header line of a block of lines with version-specific information, by looking for substring `## Version`  at the start (`^`) of the line and, if found, executing the associated code block (`{ ... }`):

  - `if (p) { exit }` exits (stops processing), if the `p` (print) flag has previously been set, because that implies that the block *after* the one of interest has been reached, i.e. that the block of interest has now been fully processed.
  - `if ($3 == ver) { p=1; next }` checks if the 3rd whitespace-separated field (`$3`) on the header line matches the given version number (passed via option `-v ver=1.0.5` and therefore stored in variable `ver`) and, if so, sets custom variable `p`, which serves as a flag indicating whether to print a line, to `1` and moves on to the next line (`next`), so as not to print the header line itself.
    In other words: `p` containing `1` indicates for subsequent lines that the version-specific block of interest has been entered, and that its lines should (potentially) be printed.
- Condition `p && NF` implicitly prints the line at hand if the condition matches, which is the case if the print flag `p` is set *and* (`&&`) the line at hand has at least one field (based on the number of fields being reflected in built-in variable `NF`), i.e. if the line is *non-blank*, thereby effectively skipping empty and all-whitespace lines in the block of interest.

  - Note that both operands of `&&` use *implicit* Boolean logic: a value of `0` (which a non-initialized custom variable such as `p` defaults to) is implicitly false, whereas any *nonzero* value implicitly true.

Comment: why add the `if` when `$3 == ver` will work fine..why clutter the code? same goes with other if...

Comment: sorry...i do not know if code without if will work...did not realized that it is within a brace...

Comment: I like the usage of `NF` to skip the empty lines..+1

Comment: @mklement0, exactly what I wanted, works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this great solution ! I have updated it to work with the keepachangelog convention. See my answer below

Answer (score 4):

A rather short `awk` script will extract the block you want.

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -v version="$1" '/## Version / {printit = $3 == version}; printit;' "$2"
```

A sample:

```
$ ./getVersionChanges 1.0.5 filename
## Version 1.0.5

* first foo change
* second foo change

$
```

Comment: should not `$3 == v` be `$3 == version`

Comment: the next command can be used inside the `{}` if the intent is to skip the line with the version. This is what the question has asked.

Comment: I know I'm contradicting the request, but I think it is helpful to include the header in the output (and it makes the code simpler).

Comment: Works well too, the difference with the accepted solution is that yours keeps the header of the version, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can replace /tmp/data with your file name and 'Version 1.0.5' with your search pattern. Note that this does not strip any empty lines.

```
sed  '1,/Version 1.0.5/d;/Version/Q' /tmp/data
```

Output:

```
* first foo change
* second foo change
```

**Explanation**

By default sed will print the lines. So we just change the logic to delete the lines which we do not need.

Select everything between line 1 and pattern and delete it

```
 1,/Version 1.0.5/d
```

Quit when you find the pattern

```
 /Version/Q
```

Comment: Intriguing, but to avoid false positives you should (a) escape the `.` in the version number as `\.`  (which means that with input from a variable you'd have to perform this substitution _programmatically_ first) and (b) make sure that the version number only matches on a word boundary at the end too. Also, to make sure that a potential match is also found on the _first_ line, the range should start with `0` (`0,/Version 1\.0\.5\b/`). Starting the range with `0` and using the `Q` function are _GNU_ `sed` extensions, so on BSD/macOS a more elaborate solution is required.

Comment: I update the answer to indicate that it will not strip the empty lines. Other things which you pointed out are also correct.

Answer (score 3):

## Keep a Changelog

I found out this thread while looking for a way to extract some release notes from a changelog written with the [keepachangelog](https://keepachangelog.com/) convention.

I have adapted @mklement0's answer to make it work with this convention.

#### Shell

```sh
awk -v ver=1.0.5 '
 /^#+ \[/ { if (p) { exit }; if ($2 == "["ver"]") { p=1; next} } p && NF
' file
```

#### Script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v ver="$1" '
 /^#+ \[/ { if (p) { exit }; if ($2 == "["ver"]") { p=1; next} } p && NF
' "$2"
```

Comment: Nice; didn't know about this changelog format.

Answer (score 3):

Building off of @mklement0's great answer, here's a rather scuffed version (forgive my lack of AWK script knowledge) that works with [Conventional Changelog](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog) with the assumptions:

- `##` or `###` starts the version line
- Followed up immediately by a space and a semantic version number that may or may not be surrounded with brackets (e.g. either `## 1.23.456` or  `## [1.23.456](http://github.com/etc)`)

Unlike the OP, I...

- Want to keep the version line (if you don't want to keep the version line, add `next` after `p = 1` like `p = 1; next`).
- Want to retain linebreaks (if you want to remove linebreaks, add `NF` after `p` like `p && NF`)

**CHANGELOG.md**

```
# Change Log

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
See [Conventional Commits](https://conventionalcommits.org) for commit guidelines.

## [1.23.456](https://github.com/your-org/your-repo/branches/compare/foo@1.23.456%foo@1.23.455) (2022-10-19)

**Note:** Version bump only for package foo

## 1.23.455 (2022-10-19)

**Note:** Version bump only for package foo

### Bug fixes

* **css:** Some style fix
* **js:** Some js fix
* **html:** Some html fix

### Features
* **js:** Some js feature
```

**AWK**

```bash
awk -v ver=5.1.30 '
 /^(##|###) \[?[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+/ {
    if (p) { exit };
    if (index($2, "[")) {
        split($2, a, "[");
        split(a[2], a, "]");
        if (a[1] == ver) {
            p = 1
        }
    } else {
        if ($2 == ver) {
            p = 1
        }
    }
} p
' path/to/CHANGELOG.md
```

`awk -v ver=1.23.456 ...`

```
## [1.23.456](https://github.com/your-org/your-repo/branches/compare/foo@1.23.456%foo@1.23.455) (2022-10-19)

**Note:** Version bump only for package foo
```

`awk -v ver=1.23.455 ...`

```
## 1.23.455 (2022-10-19)

**Note:** Version bump only for package foo

### Bug fixes

* **css:** Some style fix
* **js:** Some js fix
* **html:** Some html fix

### Features
* **js:** Some js feature
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! Other answers didn't work with links following the [] brackets